# YouTube Data API for anonymous search

Tags: r, search, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the YouTube Data API v3.0 for a project querying many videos. I am looking to recapitulate how a search would be done on incognito mode in a browser, such that previous browsing history does not influence search results, but am trying to avoid searching manually on incognito mode. Hence, what I have done is created a new, unused Google account (since I have read that browsing data is associated with one's Google account [1](https://www.google.com/chrome/privacy/whitepaper.html)) and used this for making a new YouTube API account and project. Then, I logged into this account to run the YouTube API in R. I am wondering if this is an acceptable method to recapitulate searching on incognito mode? If not, any recommendations? Would it be wise to clear browser history before running YouTube API in R - if so, which browser does YouTube API leverage - Chrome? I would really appreciate any assistance/advice, as I am very new to this and haven't been able to find any resources online for how "anonymous" YouTube API searches are or how exactly it works in the background. Thanks.

Edit: I do notice that running the YouTube API in R and pulling search results gives me different results versus when I perform the same search on incognito mode. Hence my question of whether YouTube API relies on your own Google account's stored data and/or your local browsing history (i.e., is YouTube API "incognito", in a sense?)

Comment: `I have read that browsing data is associated with one's Google account` = where do you read this? I really don't know if the search feature of YouTube Data API has any to do with the user's browser history. If you can provide more info (*by [edit] your question*) with what you have done so far, maybe I or anyone else can help you further.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Your question appears to be opinion based. We can not recommend to you how to best solve your issue.  We can advise you on how to fix your issues if you have errros.